# Iterating a sequence and verifying its convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, sequence-of-function

I am given a sequence $(f_n)_n$ where $n\in N$. $f_n : \Re \rightarrow \Re: x \mapsto 1$

$f_1:\Re \rightarrow \Re$ is defined as follows

$$f_1 (x) = 1 + \int_0^x f_0 (t) dt$$

One sees that the sequence has to be:

$$f_{n+1} (x) = 1 + \int_0^x f_n (t) dt$$

Now I want to compute the value of these functions. One gets:

For $n = 0$

$$f_{1} (x) = 1 + \int_0^x f_0 (t) dt$$

(the provided one).

For $n = 1$

$$f_{2} (x) = 1 + \int_0^x f_1 (t) dt$$

For $n = 2$

$$f_{3} (x) = 1 + \int_0^x f_2 (t) dt$$

$$...$$

Basically what I am doing here is iterating and what I have finally got is:

Knowing that $f_n : \Re \rightarrow \Re: x \mapsto 1$

$$f_{1} (x) = 1 + x$$

$$f_{2} (x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}$$

$$f_{2} (x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6}$$

$$...$$

**Thus the sequence** $(f_n)_n$ **does not seem to converge while it should...**

What's wrong with my reasoning?

**I am also curious on how could I prove the convergence of a sequence which includes an integral on it.** I have been studying the convergence of a sequence theorem and understood it. I have applied it to straightforward examples but never to a sequence with an integral on it. **How could I do so?**

EDIT:

So we get that

$$f_{n+1} (x) = \sum_{n}^{N} x^{n}/n!$$

Comment: Redo te computation for $f_2$, you should have $x^2/2$.

Comment: @Mindlack why, isn't $f_0 = 1$?

Comment: Sure it is. And $f_1(x)=1+x$ as well. But what is $f_2$?

Comment: Look at fixed point operators. If $(Af)(x) = 1+\int_0^x f(t)dt$, then the iteration is $f_{n+1} = A f_n$ and you are (presumably) trying to show that $f_n$ converges to the fixed point $f$ that satisfies $f=Af$.

Comment: @Mindlack $f_{2} (x) = 1 + \int_0^x (1 + x) dt = 1 + x + x^2$ because after the integral you get t + tx; then I just used Barrow's law

Comment: No. $f_2(x)=1+\int_0^x{(1+t)\,dt}=1+x+x^2/2$.

Comment: Oops I did not change the variable. Now fixing

Comment: Thank you, the main issue has been solved. However I am interested in how to deal with integrals in sequences. This case is easy because leads you to a household series and then you can apply several tests so as to see if it converges or not. But what If I do not get a polynomial expression corresponding to a known series? Then how can I prove the convergence of the sequence? Well, I am still a beginner on Analysis (reading chapter 2 of Abbot's). Should I just keep reading?